# Multiple Yahtzee bonus checkmark rules: additional turn or fill blank box?

Tags: scoring, turn-order, yahtzee

Yahtzee cards have rules for multiple 5 of a kind Yahtzees:

> ✔️ FOR EACH BONUS
> SCORE 100 PER ✔️

[image: multiple Yahtzee checkmark rules]

Imagine I've already rolled and marked `50` for my first Yahtzee. On my next turn I roll another Yahtzee.

Do I mark a normal scoring box, in addition to the ✔️? Can I mark this Yahtzee as a `100` point bonus *and* fill in a slot for the upper corresponding number, 3 of a Kind, 4 of a Kind, or Chance?

If those boxes are already filled, am I forced to mark `0` for one of the few remaining empty boxes? A Yahtzee would seemingly score `0` for Small Straight, Large Straight, Full House, and 5 of the 6 upper number boxes.

Or do I only mark ✔️ for `100` points, then have an *additional turn* (set of 3 rolls) to fill the scoring box that I didn't use in favor of a ✔️ Yahtzee Bonus?

What happens to my turn / boxes if I roll additional Yahtzees?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I mark a normal scoring box, in addition to the ✔️?

Yes.

> Can I mark this Yahtzee as a 100 point bonus and fill in a slot for the upper corresponding number, 3 of a Kind, 4 of a Kind, or Chance?

Yes, with priority given to the upper box. (At least, according to the rules linked below. If your copy of the rules differs, use that, of course.)

> If those boxes are already filled, am I forced to mark 0 for one of the few remaining empty boxes?

Yes, if you put it in the upper section.

> A Yahtzee would score 0 for Small Straight, Large Straight, Full House, and 5 of the 6 upper number boxes.

You get full normal points for straights and full houses.

From [these rules](http://www.yahtzee.org.uk/rules.html):

> If you roll a second Yahtzee in a game, and you scored your first yahtzee in the Yahtzee box, you would score a further bonus 100 points in the yahtzee box. You must also put this roll into another category, as follows;
>
> - If the corresponding Upper section category is not filled then you must score there.
>   ie if you rolled 4 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 4 and the Fours Category is not filled, you must put the score in the Fours category.
> - If the corresponding Upper section category is filled you may then put the score anywhere on the Upper Section (scoring zero). In 3 of a Kind, 4 of a Kind, and Chance categories you would score the total of the die faces. For the Small Straight, Large Straight, and Full House categories, you would score 30, 40 and 25 points respectively.